# Many UDP sockets on different ports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
var dgram = require("dgram");

var start = 27015;

for(var i = start; i < (start + 100); i++)
{
    var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

    server.on("message", function(msg, sender) {
        console.log(server.address().port)
    });

    server.bind(i);
}
```

Why it always output **last** port (27114) ?

What's wrong? I thought it would help identify the port of the receiving server.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that it only binds to port 27114?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben, no servers bound successfully to all 100 ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a closure to capture the `server` for the callback:

```
server.on("message", (function (server) {
    return function (msg, sender) {
        console.log(server.address().port);
    };
})(server));
```

And I'm not sure of how the `on` method works, but in normal JavaScript event handling, `this` refers to the object the event applies to. So you might be able to forget the closure and just use `this.address().port` to refer to the specific `server` that the event is happening to.

Another way to set it up is with:

```
server.on("message", getOnHandler(server));

function getOnHandler(s) {
    return function (msg, sender) {
        console.log(s.address().port);
    };
}
```

Comment: @SébastienRenauld What do you mean?

Comment: Meh, two different methods. I've hoisted `port` in a closure, you hoisted `server` itself. Both will work.

Comment: Deleted mine, as our methods are exactly identical in the way they work.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Well let's talk about it. (I think you can see the comment on your deleted answer). I think the only problem is that the event handler executes asynchronously, and by the time it does, `server` (inside of the callback), refers to the last one created from the for loop. So I don't think it has anything to do with the `port`. Although since the port from the loop should always be the same as `server.address().port`, it could be safe. But to me, you should get the reference to the event's target (in case they want more than just the port).

Comment: in my version, I create the `server` local var in the closure from the port. As a result, both of them are safe. This is the main difference.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Ahh I see I see. That's usually how I do it - put the whole body of the loop into a closure. I kinda like yours better :) Even though they accomplish the same

Comment: @Ian: undeleted. Feel free to +1 or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Ian is on the right track - you need a closure. However, his way will cause a server dereference.

```
for(var i = start; i < (start + 100); i++) {
  (function(port) {
    var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

    server.on("message", function(msg, sender) {
     console.log(server.address().port)
    });
    server.bind(port);
  })(i);
 }
```

This will cause each `server` instance to be isolated within a closure but not dereferenced. They will keep existing, without being overwritten through scope issues.

Answer (score 1):

You've fallen victim of variable hoisting and lexical scope.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
var dgram = require("dgram");
var start = 27015;
var i;
var server;

for(i = start; i < (start + 100); i++)
{
    server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

    server.on("message", function(msg, sender) {
        console.log(server.address().port)
    });

}
```

This means that `server` is always going to be the last assignment to server inside of the callback (well, technically it's going to be whatever value `server` points to when the callback is executed -- unless it's called during the binding though, it's always going to be the last one).

You can use a closure as Ian suggested, but I suspect that `this` will also be set to the server inside of the callback. (Or at least some way to access it. You'd have to check the docs.)